# Issue with CakePHP 2 find method with JOIN

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

> I am facing an issue with CakePHP **Find** method with **JOIN** and **bindModel**.
>
> I have 2 tables,  **Customer** and **Order**.
> Order table has all order records for Customer.

Now in one Query, I need `Customer record` with `Total` due or total ordered amount.

When I try to use this query, It returns only one record.

```
$this->Customer->bindModel(['hasOne'=>['Order'=>['fields'=>['SUM(Order.due_amount) as due']]]],false);

$data = $this->Customer->find('all',[ 'conditions' => [ 'Customer.type' => 2,'Customer.status'=>1] ]);
```

2nd , When i try to use JOIN , still not getting correct result

```
$data = $this->Customer->find('all',[
'conditions' => [ 'Customer.type' => 2,'Customer.status'=>1],
'joins' =>[[ 'table' => 'orders', 'alias' => 'Order',
'type' => 'RIGHT', /*LEFT/INNER*/
'fields'=>['SUM(Order.due_amount) as due'],
'conditions' => [ 'Order.customer_id = Customer.id']]]]);
```

Using both method i am not getting correct result

I need result like this

```
Array( 
            [0] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( /*all Customer table fields */ ) [Order] => Array ( [due] => 125.25))
            [1] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( /*all Customer table fields */ ) [Order] => Array ( [due] => 10.00))
            [2] => Array ( [Customer] => Array ( /*all Customer table fields */ ) [Order] => Array ( [due] => 500.10))
.... so on 
            )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use below query

```
$joins = array(
        array('table' => 'orders',
            'alias' => 'Order',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array(
                'Order.customer_id = Customer.id',
            )
        )
    );
    $conditions = [];
    $conditions[] = ['Customer.type' => 2];
    $conditions[] = ['Customer.status'=>1];
    $this->Customer->virtualFields['total_due'] = "sum(Order.due_amount)";
    $data_array = $this->Customer->find('all', ['conditions' => $conditions, 'group' => 'Customer.id', 'joins' => $joins, 'fields' => ['Customer.*', 'Customer.total_due']]);
```